# What do you call the y shaped support for the camera in this weird camera apparatus?

Tags: word-request

[image]

There is the weird support attached to the weird bar with 2 handles that's shaped like a curved Y, what do you call this set of metallic bars? Is there a name for it, what is the general term and the specific term for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a [**camera stabilizer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_stabilizer).

It allows a camera to be carried around while keeping the image steady.

One well-known brand is [**Steadicam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steadicam) and this term has become used generically.